# TI-83 Series Graphing Calculator Emulator

Tags: emulation, software, ti-83, calculator

Back in middle school I set up a Windows/DOS TI-83 calculator emulator for some of my teachers.  I can't for the life of me remember the name, but I'm looking for a Mac TI-83 emulator (or any TI-8x family of calculators, TI-83 Plus, TI-84, etc) for Mac.  Anyone know of any Mac or cross-platform solutions?

Comment: This seems to be a test question based on this [meta question](http://meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/181/12). I see no reason why this doesn't belong here. There is a large and vibrant community of programmable calculator hackers that should be welcome here.

Comment: One question per post, please. I edited the second related question out, but it would make a fine new question. (And nice catch of my typo.)

Comment: Thanks @jdv, new question [here](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1045/621).

Comment: This has come up in the close votes queue. I will not vote (since I am a mod it would be binding) but others should. If this question remains, I (or somebody else) will make a tag for it, but if not...

Comment: I would consider this on-topic.  I certainly considered and used my TI-81 as a portable computer at the time so I don't see why it wouldn't count as a retro-computer now.

Comment: I consider this off-topic, as TI are still selling TI-83+ calculators that are compatible with the TI-83. So they're not remotely retro.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Wabbitemu](http://wabbitemu.org/) is a modern emulator supporting many TI platforms, it supports TI-73, TI-81, TI-82, TI-83, TI-83+(SE), TI-84+(SE), TI-84+CSE, TI-85, and TI-86