# TI-BASIC Interpreter for Mac

Tags: software-recommendation, ti-83, calculator, ti-basic

I've been trying to golf more in TI-BASIC and was wondering if there was an interpreter available for Mac.  Bonus points if it is still being actively maintained.

Comment: Do you have a preference for some (or all) major versions of TI-BASIC?

Comment: @jdv Great question.  I'm not too familiar with the versions outside of the TI-83/84 range.  If there are different emulators which support different versions, can you elaborate on that in your answer?

Comment: I'm not the right person to answer, but there was a major change between 83/84 and the next-gen devices, and the BASIC changed accordingly. A _good_ answer should discuss device/version support (hint, hint).

Comment: Good points.  I'm also forgetting about the Nspire suite which came with its own emulator and presumably updates to the language.

Comment: That being said, I bet _you_ could easily come up with an answer with some web searches. There is at least one on Sourceforge, and there are some links found off of wikibooks and other "ti calc" clearinghouse sites. Someone just needs to make an overview of the state of affairs so the answer isn't just a list of links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://js99er.net/) is a TI 99/4a emulator written in JavaScript that runs in a web browser. When it starts up, press any key to begin, then press 1 for TI BASIC. This brings you to the BASIC interpreter.

[MAME](http://mamedev.org/release.html) as of v0.162 contains a TI 99/4a emulator. Binaries are available for Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Comment: Good find!  There's a fairly good chance that the JS99'er may keep me from getting some work done today...

Comment: @Aaron try it with the speech synthesizer.  Great fun.

Answer (score 1):

**(This is a work-in-progress answer I hope to expand on as I continue to evaluate options.)**

I've found two so far that I am currently evaluating:

[pitybas](https://github.com/lunixbochs/pitybas), which claims to be a faithful interpreter written in Python.

[tibasic](http://tibasic.sourceforge.net/), written in C++. Windows binaries are provided, with a Mac/Linux version supposedly in development. There has been no news on this since 2012. This is not actually an interpreter, but rather claims to compile to a format [suitable for direct TI-83/83+/84+ device development](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tibasic/).

Comment: @jdv Thanks for the edit, should have noted that tibasic creates actual binaries.

Comment: Once assumes you could use tibasic to make a blob that could be run on an emulator from the linked question..